# If rational $a$, $b$, $c$ satisfy ${1\over{a+bc}}+{1\over{b+ac}}={1\over{a+b}}$, show $\sqrt{(c − 3)(c + 1)}$ is rational

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $a, b, c$ are rational numbers such that $a + bc, b + ac$ and $a + b$ are non-zero, and satisfy
$${1\over{a+bc}}+{1\over{b+ac}}={1\over{a+b}}$$
Prove that $\sqrt{(c − 3)(c + 1)}$ is rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach is to try to show that the radicand is a perfect square.

Since $a, b, c$ are rational, therefore $a+bc, b+ac$ and $a+b$ are rational.

Also the given relation is rational.

So try to show that $(c-3)(c+1)$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Thanks, that worked @easymathematics. I was able to get a quadratic equation in a to make it a perfect square